# "complete data" vs. "whole data"

Tags: word-usage

Imagine we have 150 apples, randomly divide them into 5 group and randomly pick one group to stat the weight of each and whether each is rotten. When the job is done, we have 30 records of data.

I guess the stats about all 150 apples would be called the "**whole data**", a record of data that has both the weight and quality is called "**complete data**", a record of data that lacks the weight, the quality, or both, is called "**incomplete data**".

Is my understanding right?

Why would I have this question? Because a post says

> In this approach we randomly split the **complete** data into training and test sets.

where the author uses "complete data" to refer to all 150 records of data.

The uses of "complete data" in [books.google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22complete%20data%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) seem to be the way I use it.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as what you are talking about here, both `whole` and `complete` mean exactly the same thing. (In other contexts there are very slight difference in nuance.)

As you have effectively said yourself, `complete` is the more common terminology currently, particularly in more formal contexts, but I believe that `whole` is in more common usage generally.